# Can you "copy" a Gemalto hardware MFA device with a virtual app?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

We use the Gemalto MFA fob with AWS. It is a given that we know the fob's serial number that was provided to AWS; I presume that serial number constitutes the "secret key" and the TOTP algorithm generates time-based codes from that seed. I was curious whether that hardware device could be replicated by a virtual device in software using the same seed and TOTP algorithm. Do any apps or services exist to do so?

Comment: The serial number is not the key, the shared secret is split between the inside of the token (intended to be tamper-resistant), and the authentication server, loaded at the time you buy the tokens. There can be software based tokens which do the same thing, but if the system is any good you can't move from an existing hardware token to a software one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25249610/478656 for some discussion and links for problems RSA SecurID had with this.

Comment: Thanks. To activate the device, I only provided two pieces of information to Amazon:
1. The serial number.
2. Two successive hashes from the device.

At no time was any information from Amazon returned to the device during that activation.

Perhaps, as you say, the device was "pre-registered" with Amazon at the time of manufacture and by providing the serial number I was just enabling AWS to look up the actual shared secret that it had stashed somewhere.

Comment: I am not familiar with how Amazon uses them, but generally you get (for example) 200 keyfobs at a company, upload 200 sets data into the MFA server, then give the keyfobs to people, and let them identify to the server which one they got, so it can connect the right token secret to their user account (that could be you giving the serial number). The two token codes help it sync - the server keeps "the current" OTP it's expecting, and ~10-100 before/after, so you don't get locked out forever if you waste one. It then adjusts when it learns where in the stream you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible -- it would be a substantial weakness in any such device if it were possible to extract its secret key.

However, if you simply switch to using a virtual device (app), when you set it up, you're provided the secret key used to initialize the device (as a string of characters or a QR code)... which you can use to initialize any number of virtual devices, and they will all display the same code at the same time, as long as their clocks are correct, because the times are anchored to the Unix epoch (not of necessity, but they are in this case).

The merits and risks of such a practice are out of the scope of this answer, but technically speaking, this works.

Comment: Thanks, I thought just a serial number would be rather weak. It hadn't occurred to be until now that the entire device might actually have been "pre-registered" with Amazon specifically to create the real shared secret, so that it can't really be used anywhere else.

Comment: Are you answering this with knowledge of the Amazon / Gemalto specifically? My experience of Gemalto SafeNet MobilePass(+) software tokens is that you can only initialize them once, and doing so on the app contacts the server and completes the provisioning process for that token, and I think that prevents the use of more than one virtual device. (If you could use more than one, wouldn't that mean many people could get away with paying only a single license?). I'd be interested to be wrong, though.

Comment: Not Gemalto but with AWS Virtual MFA.  Unless there has been a significant change, they give you a QR code with a secret key that you can use to initialize any app that does all the TOTP calculations internally.  No server communication is required.